# I have a problem with my Gradle. Cannot Resolve some Issues

Tags: android, gradle

Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0.

Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:25.1.0.

Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2.

its and old app that im learning from it all over again

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kaldeta.moviemania"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Did you download sdk 25 to your computer?
Also did you perform gradle sync?

Comment: change compile to "implementation" and see what happening , if you had different error write them here.

Comment: Most likely you don't have the proper repositories defined, where it could fetch them.

Comment: change compile to "implementation" compile is deprecated. For information, use target 28 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check `repositories` clause in your root build.gradle, there must be `google` reposity, like

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Also check, if gradle is in offline mode `Android Studio`->`Preferences`->`Gradle`-`Offline work` checkbox